# NativeScript - How to create a webview with request blocking/redirection?

Tags: ios, nativescript, wkwebview, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to create a webview with the capability to block/redirect certain urls requested inside the webview (not just the page url, but also the requests sent from the page, think of it as what a browser extension is able to do).

After some research, the closest I get was this Swift/Obj-c approach of use `NSUrlProtocol`: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2292-using-nsurlprotocol-with-swift, and the doc of the `native-webview-ext` mentioned something about `WKURLSchemeHandler` https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-webview-ext .

I'm new to mobile development and this feature is crucial for my project. I wonder if anyone has experience building this out in `NativeScript`, I hope I don't have to convince my team and my boss to write this in Swift instead :(.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the webview-ext plugin docs, it does support overriding resource urls. Refer the `registerLocalResource` method.

Just in case, even if that is not supported you don't have to write your whole project in Swift as you can always access all native apis from JavaScript / TypeScript itself, read more about it [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/types/ObjC-Classes).